# Different dataclass object show equal

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a simple dataclass with 3 member variables. When I create two different objects for the class and check for equality it always comes out True even if the values for the member variables is different.

**Data Class:**

```
@dataclass(init=False)
class DiagCodes:
    __slots__ = ["indx_nbr", "diag_cd", "diag_typ_cd"]

    def __init__(
        self,
        indx_nbr: Optional[int] = None,
        diag_cd: Optional[str] = None,
        diag_typ_cd: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> None:

        self.indx_nbr = indx_nbr
        self.diag_cd = diag_cd
        self.diag_typ_cd = diag_typ_cd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dc = DiagCodes(1)
    dc_empty = DiagCodes()

    print(dc == dc_empty)
```

Output:

> True

Shouldn't the output come out as false with the default implementation of `__eq__` function of the dataclass?

The python version I am working on is **Python 3.8.10**

Comment: I'm pretty sure your dataclass doesn't have any recognized fields, so all instances will be equal. You need to move your type hints into the class body, rather than only in the `__init__` signature (and from what you show, there's no reason you need to write your own `__init__` method).

Comment: I wrote the init so that I can assign a default value to the members. With slots in python 3.8 assigning them in the class gives an error. I really want to use slots because I will be creating thousands of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not really using the functionality of dataclasses here. The dataclass decorator looks for class variables with type annotations (called fields) of which you have none.

The default `__eq__` for dataclasses compares each of it's fields. Since you don't any any fields, the equality returns true.

Try the following (note you could remove init=False and the hand written __init__ method):

```
@dataclass(init=False)
class DiagCodes:
    __slots__ = ["indx_nbr", "diag_cd", "diag_typ_cd"]

    indx_nbr: Optional[int]
    diag_cd: Optional[int]
    diag_typ_cd: Optional[str]
    
    def __init__(
        self,
        indx_nbr: Optional[int] = None,
        diag_cd: Optional[str] = None,
        diag_typ_cd: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> None:

        self.indx_nbr = indx_nbr
        self.diag_cd = diag_cd
        self.diag_typ_cd = diag_typ_cd
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This worked! So does that mean I have to mention the list of fields 4 times in the dataclass (slots, class variable, init args, params)? I really want to use slots because I'll be creating hundereds of thousands of objects and in python 3.8 I can't really set a default value without the init.

Comment: There are other classes like this in the code they can have upto 100 member variables. So if I don't give a default value, every time I create an instance I will have to pass 100 parameters. Is there a better design approach?

Comment: "I can't really set a default value without the init." You can by setting a default on the field. Eg `indx_nbr: Optional[int] = None`. With that you should be able to remove the `__init__` and would only need your members in two places.

Comment: When I set the default on the field I get this error: *ValueError: 'indx_nbr' in __slots__ conflicts with class variable*

Comment: Ah sorry, I only skimmed over `__slots__` because I've never used it before. In 3.10 you can use `slots=True` in your dataclass decorator to have it generate it for you. I'm not sure what the best solution is for 3.8, or if there even is a good one.

Comment: If only I could make my org update to python 3.10 :') Thanks for your help though. I am accepting this as a solution as it solves the issue and helped me understand how dataclasses work.